# calling a function from Javascript via onlick on anchor tag doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cant seem to get to work the onlick function set on my anchor tag to display the hidden element in smaller screens. im just a newbie and still learning basic coding and im really confused right now. i know this is a very simple problem but i really want to understand how this can be fixed. im just learning web design at home.

**HTML**

```
<nav>     
    <a class="toggle" href="" onclick="openNav()"><i class="fas fa-bars" > 
</i></a>
<ul>
    <li class="current"><a class = "navlinks" href = "">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class = "navlinks" href  = "Services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a class = "navlinks" href = "About.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a class = "navlinks pointer" 
onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" 
style="width:auto;">Login</a></li>
    <li><a class = "navlinks" href  = "Signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
</ul>

</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width:800px){
ul {
display:none; 
position: fixed;
padding: 20px;
border: 2px solid #FFB600;
background:#1a1a1a;
right: 15px;
width: 50%;
border-radius: 20px 0 15px 10px;
z-index:99999;

}

toggle{display:block;}

.toggle:hover{color:white;}

nav li {
text-align: center; 
width: 100%;
padding: 10px 0;
margin: 0;
}

}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function openNav() {
document.getElementsByTagName('ul').style.display = "block";

}
```

thanks in advance to those who will help..

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a **collection**. Either use `querySelector` or index into the collection. See the linked question's answers for details. (Separately: Recommend adding a class to hide elements rather than directly manipulating their `style`.)

Comment: @Satpal - Just a nitpick: `getElementsByTagName` returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-htmlcollection), not a [`NodeList`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist) (`querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`). I only mention it because the one is "live" and the other is a snapshot, and they have *slightly* different methods available (on some browsers). For instance, in the spec, `HTMLCollection` isn't iterable and doesn't have `forEach`, but `NodeList` is and does. (Some browsers go beyond spec, though.)

Comment: As always thanks sir @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Also note that the anchor tag is empty. I'm not sure how an invisible element can be clicked.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the querySelector somehow did the job thanks to that but the fixed ul that should show up when clicking the anchor tag just disappears quickly ...i dont know whats causing the problem. does this have to do with the hidden elements that was assigned on my media query?